# How do I force my iPhone app to 480 px height on iPhone 5 and ios 6 SDK?

Tags: iphone, ios6, iphone-5

When I run my iPhone app that was compiled pre-ios6 on an iPhone 5, it renders in original 480 px with black space on the top and bottom of the screen. However, when I compile my iPhone app on the relatively new ios 6 SDK and run it on my iPhone 5, it wants to run at the new 1136 px height. However, my app is not yet designed for that height, and so there is a white space gap at the bottom. I want to release a new version of my app with bug fixes, without having to redesign the layout for iPhone 5. How can I make the iPhone 5 display the app as it did before the ios6 sdk compilation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `Default-568h@2x.png` from your target.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. It looks like I had to delete file from filesystem (removing reference was not enough), and do a clean build to get it out of the bundle.

Answer (score 1):

Please be aware that Apple requires the Default-568h@2x.png image now, submission to the App Store without will give you an invalid binary rejection.